# eliminate all subsequent numbers in lisp

Tags: list, lisp

I am new to lisp and I encountered a problem in my homework that asks to eliminate all the subsequent numbers and only the first number will be in the list
for example `(1 1 2 1 3 1 1 1)` will be `(1 2 1 3 1)`

my code is:

```
;the input is (1 1 2 1 3 1 1 1)
 (defun eli(x)
   ; this condition will check if x is empty or has only one element
  (if (or(null x)(null (cdr x))) x 
    ; if the first element is 1 but the second element is not 1
    (if (and (= 1 (car x))(not (= 1 (car (cdr x)))))
         ; if true then append 1 and call the function with the rest of the list
        (cons (car x)(eli(cdr x)))
         ; if false call the function recursivaly
        (eli(cdr x))
      )))
         ; the output is (1 2 1 3 1 1)
```

and this code generates `(1 2 1 3 1 1)`

any idea where I did wrong?

Comment: It's unclear for what input which output is generated. It's also unclear what your code should do. You might want to comment your code.

Comment: i commented my code to be clearer, note that the real output must be `(1 2 1 3 1)`. I couldn't get it

Comment: Please show us where Lisp produces the output for some input. Post the actual Lisp interaction. Add the interaction to your question.

Comment: Whoever set the problem probably intended it to work for numbers other than 1...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this predicate:

```
(and (= 1 (car x))(not (= 1 (car (cdr x))))))
```

This just checks if the first element is `1` and the second isn't. You should rather check if the first element is `numberp` and then if the two first elements are `eql` and then skip the element.